# Would white light waves act as same as monochromatic waves in double slit experiment?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, double-slit-experiment, interference

Would white light waves act as same as monochromatic waves in double slit experiment? 
If not, what pattern would be seen on the screen?

Comment: Just a remark: There are no white photons, thus no "white light waves". White light is merely the superposition of the continuous spectrum of monochromatic light.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

White light consists of many wavelengths. Hence, the interference pattern using white light appears different than that for monochromatic light. At the center point, all the waves travel the same length and hence no path difference is produced at the center point. Thus at the center point we get the maxima of all wavelengths and we obtain the maximum for white light at the center point. Slightly above or below the center point the fringes will be coloured. Watch this video for visualising this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEqwRBjHdwc